# Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, viewmodel

I get the above error when I try to initialize my ViewModelProvider from my Fragment like so:

```
    //This line gives me the error "Cannot create an instance of class..."
    SetViewModel setViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SetViewModel.class);

    final MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this.getActivity(), setViewModel, items);

    theListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My SetViewModel class:

```
public class SetViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private Repository repository;
    private static Flowable<List<Set>> sets = null;

    public SetViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new Repository(application);
    }...
```

My error:

```
2021-02-09 19:51:22.171 22202-22202/com.example.xxxxxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.xxxxxxx, PID: 22202
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.SetViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:275)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:106)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at com.example.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.MyFragment.onCreateView(MyFragment.java:88)
```

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I would have added more error but it already says I have too much code to post by edit.

Comment: Please include the full exception and what version of fragments you're using (preferably your whole `dependencies` block from your `build.gradle` file).

Answer (score 0):

Because my ViewModel extends AndroidViewModel, which requires I pass an Application, I should have referenced a ViewModelFactory that passed an Application.

```
public class SetViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    private Application mApplication;

    public SetViewModelFactory(Application application) {
        mApplication = application;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        return (T) new SetViewModel(mApplication);
    }
}
```

Then initialized my ViewModel like so:

```
SetViewModel setViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, new SetViewModelFactory(getActivity().getApplication())).get(SetViewModel.class);
```

Comment: It's not mandatory to pass an `Application` instance with a Factory object when you extends `AndroidViewModel`. I think there should be another root cause.